# FireBase Realtime Database : Recycler View not populating

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My recycler view opens, shows a black screen for some secs and then returns back to my login activity.

Here's my adapter class...

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

public class MainAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<items, MainAdapter.myViewHolder> {

    public MainAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<items> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull items model) {
        holder.Product.setText(model.getProduct());
        holder.Price.setText(model.getPrice());
        holder.Stock.setText(model.getStock());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.display_item,parent,false);
        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView Product, Price, Stock;

        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Price=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Price);
            Product=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Product);
            Stock=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Stock);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my Main class

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MainAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Main.this));
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<items> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<items>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cups"),items.class)
                        .build();

        adapter= new MainAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Toast.makeText(this, " not Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        adapter.stopListening();
    }
```

And here's the logcat(Error)  No Filters

```
2021-07-22 15:41:10.222 17121-17121/? E/facebook.katan: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-07-22 15:41:10.565 17121-17152/? E/appstatelogger2: Can't run on P or newer
2021-07-22 15:41:10.583 17121-17157/? E/dalvik-internals: attempting to hook OatFileManager::HasCollisions
2021-07-22 15:41:10.587 17121-17157/? E/dalvik-internals: could not hook _ZNK3art14OatFileManager13HasCollisionsEPKNS_7OatFileEPKNS_18ClassLoaderContextEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS7_11ch
2021-07-22 15:41:10.587 17121-17157/? E/dalvik-internals: attempting to hook OatFileAssistant::IsUpToDate
2021-07-22 15:41:10.589 17121-17157/? E/dalvik-internals: attempting to hook OatFileAssistant::IsUpToDate
2021-07-22 15:41:10.592 17121-17157/? E/dalvik-internals: could not hook _ZN3art16OatFileAssistant17OatFileIsUpToDateEv
2021-07-22 15:41:10.592 17121-17157/? E/dalvik-internals: attempting to hook OatFileAssistant::IsUpToDate
2021-07-22 15:41:10.597 17121-17157/? E/dalvik-internals: could not hook _ZN3art16OatFileAssistant18OdexFileIsUpToDateEv
2021-07-22 15:41:10.597 17121-17157/? E/dalvik-internals: attempting to hook OatFileAssistant::IsUpToDate
2021-07-22 15:41:10.600 17121-17157/? E/dalvik-internals: could not hook _ZN3art16OatFileAssistant22GivenOatFileIsUpToDateERKNS_7OatFileE
2021-07-22 15:41:10.966 17121-17157/? E/nightwatch-fd: Unable to open /proc/self/oom_adj (mode read) : 13 : Permission denied
2021-07-22 15:41:10.966 17121-17157/? E/nightwatch-fd: Unable to open /proc/self/oom_score_adj (mode read) : 13 : Permission denied
2021-07-22 15:41:11.014 1442-1442/? E/OPPO_KEVENT_RECORD: oppo_kevent Receive message from kernel, event_type=3
2021-07-22 15:41:11.014 1442-1442/? E/OPPO_KEVENT_RECORD: OPPO_KEVENT payload:10316,path@@/data/app/com.facebook.katana-A3yDUxyptfeE9lxYzQ7ziQ==/lib/arm64/libwatcher_binary.so
2021-07-22 15:41:11.016 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: /proc/zoneinfo open: errno=13
2021-07-22 15:41:11.016 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: sysmeminfo parse failed
2021-07-22 15:41:11.046 17219-17219/? A/linker: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_errorreporting/sess__000002035-1626948670386-cb5f3fa5-6e6a-0704-da63-0c86cb77ab08/nightwatch.txt": library "libclang_rt.xray.so" not found
2021-07-22 15:41:11.076 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: lmkd signal waiters
2021-07-22 15:41:11.077 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: /proc/zoneinfo open: errno=13
2021-07-22 15:41:11.077 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: sysmeminfo parse failed
2021-07-22 15:41:12.077 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: /proc/zoneinfo open: errno=13
2021-07-22 15:41:12.078 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: sysmeminfo parse failed
2021-07-22 15:41:13.120 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: /proc/zoneinfo open: errno=13
2021-07-22 15:41:13.120 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: sysmeminfo parse failed
2021-07-22 15:41:13.928 15771-15974/? E/nightwatch-target: lmkd signal waiters
2021-07-22 15:41:13.932 3156-3156/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2021-07-22 15:41:13.934 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: lmkd signal waiters
2021-07-22 15:41:13.937 3156-3156/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2021-07-22 15:41:14.126 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: /proc/zoneinfo open: errno=13
2021-07-22 15:41:14.126 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: sysmeminfo parse failed
2021-07-22 15:41:15.129 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: /proc/zoneinfo open: errno=13
2021-07-22 15:41:15.129 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: sysmeminfo parse failed
2021-07-22 15:41:16.159 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: /proc/zoneinfo open: errno=13
2021-07-22 15:41:16.159 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: sysmeminfo parse failed
2021-07-22 15:41:16.865 4914-4949/? E/OpenID: com.heytap.mcs:DUID:ret:T
2021-07-22 15:41:16.927 1789-4085/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2021-07-22 15:41:17.207 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: /proc/zoneinfo open: errno=13
2021-07-22 15:41:17.208 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: sysmeminfo parse failed
2021-07-22 15:41:17.288 1789-1789/? E/TransmessgeManager: achieve hal service failed
2021-07-22 15:41:17.420 1247-7781/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl318392684.tmp: No such file or directory
2021-07-22 15:41:17.450 1789-5223/? E/OppoPackageManager: parserFilterAppList() xml empty, return.
2021-07-22 15:41:17.559 1789-5221/? E/OppoPackageManager: parserFilterAppList() xml empty, return.
2021-07-22 15:41:17.732 3156-3156/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2021-07-22 15:41:17.744 3156-3156/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2021-07-22 15:41:17.766 1789-2123/? E/system_server: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2021-07-22 15:41:17.866 3156-3156/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2021-07-22 15:41:17.876 3156-3156/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2021-07-22 15:41:17.879 15771-15974/? E/nightwatch-target: lmkd signal waiters
2021-07-22 15:41:18.004 15740-17371/? E/route: try findMethod[market://PackageReceiverRouter/Void_onReceive_Context_Intent], result = null!!
2021-07-22 15:41:18.008 17364-17364/? E/le.silkenscoop: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-07-22 15:41:18.062 1789-4781/? E/OppoPackageManager: parserFilterAppList() xml empty, return.
2021-07-22 15:41:18.065 13654-17362/? E/route: try findMethod[gamecenter://PackageReceiverRouter/Void_onReceive_Context_Intent], result = null!!
2021-07-22 15:41:18.114 4030-4064/? E/oiface: packageSwitch pkg com.example.silkenscoops, enter
2021-07-22 15:41:18.114 4030-4064/? E/oiface: current package is com.example.silkenscoops
2021-07-22 15:41:18.127 4030-4054/? E/oiface: Average freq 0 for 0s.
2021-07-22 15:41:18.127 4030-4054/? E/oiface: Average freq 0 for 0s.
2021-07-22 15:41:18.134 4030-4054/? E/oiface: client  not found, skipped
2021-07-22 15:41:18.154 1789-3304/? E/OppoPackageManager: parserFilterAppList() xml empty, return.
2021-07-22 15:41:18.183 15771-15974/? E/nightwatch-target: lmkd signal waiters
2021-07-22 15:41:18.208 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: /proc/zoneinfo open: errno=13
2021-07-22 15:41:18.209 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: sysmeminfo parse failed
2021-07-22 15:41:18.513 774-17421/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
2021-07-22 15:41:18.518 4914-4949/? E/OpenID: com.nearme.statistics.rom:DUID:ret:T
2021-07-22 15:41:18.525 4914-4949/? E/OpenID: com.nearme.statistics.rom:OUID:ret:T
2021-07-22 15:41:18.527 4914-4949/? E/OpenID: com.nearme.statistics.rom:GUID:ret:T
2021-07-22 15:41:18.535 4914-4949/? E/OpenID: com.nearme.statistics.rom:OUID_STATUS:ret:T
2021-07-22 15:41:18.561 774-17419/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
2021-07-22 15:41:18.707 1789-3252/? E/WindowManager: App trying to use insecure INPUT_FEATURE_NO_INPUT_CHANNEL flag. Ignoring
2021-07-22 15:41:18.871 15771-15974/? E/nightwatch-target: lmkd signal waiters
2021-07-22 15:41:19.068 3641-14933/? E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Called cancelTask for already completed task com.google.android.gms/.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService{u=0 tag="Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG" trigger=window{start=149s,end=299s,earliest=-547s,latest=-397s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=-696s last_run=-380s exec_window_multiplier=1.0000 jid=N/A status=ACTIVE retries=0 client_lib=GMS_TASK_SCHEDULER-212418000} :1 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
2021-07-22 15:41:19.182 6857-6857/? E/ANR_LOG: >>> msg's executing time is too long
2021-07-22 15:41:19.182 6857-6857/? E/ANR_LOG: Blocked msg = { when=-1s615ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=wyd } , cost  = 1615 ms
2021-07-22 15:41:19.182 6857-6857/? E/ANR_LOG: >>>Current msg List is:
2021-07-22 15:41:19.183 6857-6857/? E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <1>  = { when=-1s190ms what=113 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ReceiverData{intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.silkenscoops flg=0x4000010 pkg=com.android.vending cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.packagemanager.impl.PackageMonitorReceiverImpl$RegisteredReceiver (has extras) } packageName=com.android.vending resultCode=0 resultData=null resultExtras=null} }
2021-07-22 15:41:19.183 6857-6857/? E/ANR_LOG: >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
2021-07-22 15:41:19.227 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: /proc/zoneinfo open: errno=13
2021-07-22 15:41:19.227 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: sysmeminfo parse failed
2021-07-22 15:41:19.258 774-17460/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
2021-07-22 15:41:19.313 17121-17465/? E/fb4a.VpsReliableMediaMonitorImpl: TigonVideoService initHybrid
2021-07-22 15:41:19.367 870-870/? E/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_set_parameters: str_params NULL
2021-07-22 15:41:19.386 774-17469/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
2021-07-22 15:41:19.396 1319-1319/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Unsupported output color format for c2d (2141391876)
2021-07-22 15:41:19.396 1319-1319/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Setting color format failed
2021-07-22 15:41:19.413 870-870/? E/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_set_parameters: str_params NULL
2021-07-22 15:41:19.425 1319-1319/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Unsupported output color format for c2d (2141391876)
2021-07-22 15:41:19.425 1319-1319/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Setting color format failed
2021-07-22 15:41:20.251 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: /proc/zoneinfo open: errno=13
2021-07-22 15:41:20.251 17121-17217/? E/nightwatch-target: sysmeminfo parse failed
2021-07-22 15:41:21.084 893-7160/? E/sensors-hal: handle_sns_client_event:85, device_orient_event: ts=941099097576, type=0
2021-07-22 15:41:21.898 1789-4085/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2021-07-22 15:41:21.940 1271-1374/? E/statsd: Found dropped events: 1 error -19 last atom tag 83 from uid 10341
2021-07-22 15:41:21.976 4026-4061/? E/hypnusd: same package name, skip
2021-07-22 15:41:22.045 3641-8492/? E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Called cancelTask for already completed task com.google.android.gms/.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService{u=0 tag="Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG" trigger=window{start=149s,end=299s,earliest=-550s,latest=-400s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=-699s last_run=-383s exec_window_multiplier=1.0000 jid=N/A status=ACTIVE retries=0 client_lib=GMS_TASK_SCHEDULER-212418000} :1 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
2021-07-22 15:41:22.068 1789-1903/? E/WindowManager: App trying to use insecure INPUT_FEATURE_NO_INPUT_CHANNEL flag. Ignoring
2021-07-22 15:41:22.134 919-973/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: Failed to update node /proc/sys/kernel/sched_upmigrate with value 50
2021-07-22 15:41:22.134 919-973/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to reset optimization [3, 7]
2021-07-22 15:41:22.144 3641-8492/? E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Called cancelTask for already completed task com.google.android.gms/.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService{u=0 tag="Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG" trigger=window{start=149s,end=299s,earliest=-551s,latest=-401s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=-700s last_run=-383s exec_window_multiplier=1.0000 jid=N/A status=ACTIVE retries=0 client_lib=GMS_TASK_SCHEDULER-212418000} :1 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
2021-07-22 15:41:22.891 17512-17512/? E/.android.gms.u: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-07-22 15:41:25.554 1789-4085/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2021-07-22 15:41:27.812 893-7160/? E/sensors-hal: handle_sns_client_event:85, device_orient_event: ts=947777859428, type=4
2021-07-22 15:41:28.581 1789-5223/? E/WindowManager: App trying to use insecure INPUT_FEATURE_NO_INPUT_CHANNEL flag. Ignoring
2021-07-22 15:41:28.634 4026-17555/? E/hypnusd: same package name, skip
2021-07-22 15:41:28.700 1789-1903/? E/WindowManager: App trying to use insecure INPUT_FEATURE_NO_INPUT_CHANNEL flag. Ignoring
2021-07-22 15:41:28.754 919-973/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: Failed to update node /proc/sys/kernel/sched_upmigrate with value 50
2021-07-22 15:41:28.755 919-973/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to reset optimization [3, 7]
2021-07-22 15:41:28.828 3641-14933/? E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Called cancelTask for already completed task com.google.android.gms/.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService{u=0 tag="Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG" trigger=window{start=149s,end=299s,earliest=-557s,latest=-407s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=-706s last_run=-390s exec_window_multiplier=1.0000 jid=N/A status=ACTIVE retries=0 client_lib=GMS_TASK_SCHEDULER-212418000} :1 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
2021-07-22 15:41:28.847 3641-8492/? E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Called cancelTask for already completed task com.google.android.gms/.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService{u=0 tag="Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG" trigger=window{start=149s,end=299s,earliest=-557s,latest=-407s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=-706s last_run=-390s exec_window_multiplier=1.0000 jid=N/A status=ACTIVE retries=0 client_lib=GMS_TASK_SCHEDULER-212418000} :1 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
2021-07-22 15:41:29.048 774-17577/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
2021-07-22 15:41:29.901 17364-17364/com.example.silkenscoops E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.silkenscoops, PID: 17364
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.example.silkenscoops.Items
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:29)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:15)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:36)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:109)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:149)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22194)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6366)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22194)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6366)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22194)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6366)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22194)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6366)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22194)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6366)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1845)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22194)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6366)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:843)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22194)
2021-07-22 15:41:29.901 17364-17364/com.example.silkenscoops E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6366)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3427)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2895)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8203)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1085)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:908)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:835)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1070)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7820)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
2021-07-22 15:41:29.956 1789-2538/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'ad85a03 com.example.silkenscoops/com.example.silkenscoops.Main (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2021-07-22 15:41:29.956 1789-2538/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'a2274e Toast (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2021-07-22 15:41:29.956 1789-2538/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'b78fdd2 com.example.silkenscoops/com.example.silkenscoops.loginActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2021-07-22 15:41:29.964 1789-2538/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '2c2077b com.example.silkenscoops/com.example.silkenscoops.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2021-07-22 15:41:30.093 17592-17592/? E/le.silkenscoop: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-07-22 15:41:30.115 4026-17555/? E/hypnusd: same package name, skip
2021-07-22 15:41:30.489 1789-4787/? E/WindowManager: App trying to use insecure INPUT_FEATURE_NO_INPUT_CHANNEL flag. Ignoring
2021-07-22 15:41:30.521 1789-2120/? E/system_server: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2021-07-22 15:41:30.601 1789-4787/? E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{2031ddb u0 android} has no registered input channel
2021-07-22 15:41:30.657 3641-14933/? E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Called cancelTask for already completed task com.google.android.gms/.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService{u=0 tag="Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG" trigger=window{start=149s,end=299s,earliest=-559s,latest=-409s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=-708s last_run=-392s exec_window_multiplier=1.0000 jid=N/A status=ACTIVE retries=0 client_lib=GMS_TASK_SCHEDULER-212418000} :1 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
2021-07-22 15:41:32.126 1789-4085/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2021-07-22 15:41:32.420 895-2622/? E/android.hardware.usb@1.0-service: uevent received SUBSYSTEM=dual_role_usb
2021-07-22 15:41:33.422 8117-17665/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-07-22 15:41:46.438 15771-15974/? E/nightwatch-target: lmkd signal waiters
2021-07-22 15:42:21.673 17726-17726/? E/earme.romupdat: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-07-22 15:42:26.929 17750-17750/? E/com.oppo.lfeh: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-07-22 15:44:28.907 4914-4949/? E/OpenID: com.nearme.statistics.rom:DUID:ret:T
2021-07-22 15:44:28.911 4914-4949/? E/OpenID: com.nearme.statistics.rom:OUID:ret:T
2021-07-22 15:44:28.914 4914-4949/? E/OpenID: com.nearme.statistics.rom:GUID:ret:T
2021-07-22 15:44:28.917 4914-4949/? E/OpenID: com.nearme.statistics.rom:OUID_STATUS:ret:T
2021-07-22 15:45:17.441 1789-2524/? E/OppoKillerManagerService: o-kill [16929] com.coloros.wirelesssettings
2021-07-22 15:45:57.372 1789-2152/? E/AppIdleHistory: Error writing app idle file for user 0
2021-07-22 15:45:57.391 1789-2152/? E/AppIdleHistory: Error writing app idle file for user 999
2021-07-22 15:46:01.933 17842-17842/? E/ogle.android.g: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-07-22 15:46:02.495 17842-17939/? E/arrg: Sync subscriptions not available
2021-07-22 15:46:04.105 17842-17856/? E/DataBuffer: Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@e1d3467)
2021-07-22 15:46:33.548 8117-17993/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-07-22 15:46:35.658 15771-15974/? E/nightwatch-target: lmkd signal waiters
```

my items class

```
import com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName;

class Items {
    private String price, stock, product;
    
    public Items() {}

    @PropertyName("Price")
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @PropertyName("Stock")
    public String getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(String stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @PropertyName("Product")
    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

Manifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.silkenscoops">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SilkenScoops">
        <activity android:name=".Main"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".loginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.1')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:7.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
}
```

FYI: Internet permission is given rules in Firebase is true for both read and write. Android Studio is at the latest version.

My database is like this: [image: database].

The problem is that as soon as I log in, instead of showing data it draws me back to the login activity.
Seems like the query and all doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any crash?

Comment: Hey..thanks for the attention..yeah it crashes and return back to my login activity..the logcat shows no error thou...if I remove the set adapter the RecyclerView doesn't crash anymore but a blank dark screen

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1khJrlP4ZLxuB8a03tlx8Hm8FApj2S_dt/view?usp=drivesdk (Here's the video of the app)

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Those are all warnings, no Exceptions. Can please check again?

Comment: Where can i find them....in logcat there is no exception...im a complete newbie so plz help me

Comment: Try to filter them by Error in Android Studio.

Comment: Is it OK now! i copied the whole error logcat here...please help

Comment: Is it OK now! i copied the whole error logcat here...please help...Regex button was unticked and no filters option I've used then only i got a bunch of errors...if i select show only selected application option the only error is 2021-07-22 12:59:44.061 18594-18594/? E/le.silkenscoop: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: price

Because you have in your `items` class a field called `Price` which is defined as `public`. This means that you'll be able to set a value directly on the fields, without the need of a setter, which is provided by default. Besides that, a getter will also be provided for you by default. Since you explicitly added a new getter in your class:

```
public String getPrice() {
    return Price;
}
```

It means that you have **duplicate** getters. This means that the one from your code is conflicting with the default one, hence the above error.

To solve this, you should simply set all the properties in your `items` class as `private`. In this way, you'll tell the compiler that only one getter is available.

Even if you do the following change:

```
private String Price;
```

There is **still** an issue. So the problem in your code lies in the fact that you have in your `items` class a field named `Price` and the getter you have defined is called `getPrice()`, which is **not** correct since Firebase is looking in the database for a field named `price` and not `Price`. See the lowercase `p` letter vs. capital letter `P`?

Now, there are two ways in which you can solve this problem. The first one would be to change your model class by renaming the fields according to the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions). So your model class should look like this:

```
class Items {
    private String price, stock, product;
    
    public Items() {}

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(String stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

See in this example, there are `private` fields (lower-case) and `public` getters. Besides that, the class name starts with `I` capital.

There is also a simpler solution, which is to set the value directly on public fields with a minimum declaration of the class, like this:

```
class Items {
    public String price, stock, product;
}
```

Now just remove the current data and add it again using the correct (lower-case) names. This solution will work only if you are in the testing phase.

There is also another approach, which is to use "annotations". So if you prefer to use private fields and public getters, you should add the [PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) annotation **only** in front of the getters. So your `Items` class should look like this:

```
class Items {
    private String price, stock, product;
    
    public Items() {}

    @PropertyName("Price")
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @PropertyName("Price")
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @PropertyName("Stock")
    public String getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    @PropertyName("Stock")
    public void setStock(String stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @PropertyName("Product")
    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    @PropertyName("Product")
    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

Meaning that you tell Firebase to look after fields that start with a capital letter.

Comment: how my adapter class will look like if i use property...the get functions are now giving errors

Comment: Most likely, there is nothing you should do in your adapter class unless you are using the public fields. Which solution have you implemented?

Comment: which solution you recommend so i can use my exisiting database without changing...the database with words starting with Caps

Comment: Good, so you added the annotations in front of the getters and you set the fields as private. Does it work now?

Comment: NO still the crash exist:(

Comment: im updating the logcat again...please check...im so frustrated...please help man

Comment: I cannot see any new crash log. Have you saved the new changes?

Comment: just did..please check.,...the crash is just like before...recycer view starts and goes back to login page

Comment: Try to make all fields lower-case and tell me if it works.

Comment: As in my updated answer, when using annotations. Looking forward to seeing your feedback.

Comment: no man i updated my logcat and items..see...not working....THE CRASH IS STILL THERE

Comment: btw , HAVE YOU SEEN MY DATABASE?....cuz in my database every word starts with caps...LINK-https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqXlw.png

Comment: Yes, doesn't matter if it starts with "caps", as long as you add the correct annotation.  Have you set the fields using lower-case letters? Check also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849).

Comment: I just copied your annotations code and replaced it in my items.java class and then also the same problem...the recycler view opens and returns back to login Activity

Comment: Check again, and provide me the entire **new** error message.

Comment: updated the new errors logcat and this error I got when i set the filter to no filter in error. if i select show only selected application, the error i get in logcat is 2021-07-22 15:29:41.613 14975-14975/? E/le.silkenscoop: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

Comment: I see, try now to ad the same annotations in front of the setters, as well, as in my updated answer.

Comment: Didn't work out. Same crash still happening...Updated the logcat..

Comment: I am not getting why its happening like this...Earlier i retrieved data of one key using Datasnapshot but now when i want the whole class, it just wont work

Comment: I usually don't do this, but I cannot understand why it doesn't work. A quick TeamViewer?

Comment: OK lets do it  ...so how to do it like will you send link or something

Comment: Send it here, and then delete it

Comment: You have instagram or fb?